# How to say "person who invites another person" with one word?

Tags: word-request

For example, we can simplify "a person who is invited by somebody" as "invitee". And does a short form exist for "a person who invites another person"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Inviter** is someone that invites.

Generally, the thing that instigates the action will have an *-er* ending, and the thing that is in receipt will have *-ee* ending.

> Inviter - someone who invites
>
> Invitee - someone who is invited
>
> Employer - someone who employs
>
> Employee -  someone who is employed

Comment: But some agent nouns sound very unnatural, and are rarely used.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, this is true. And has been suggested 'host' or some other word might be more natural, depending on context.

Comment: Well, someone who conducts isn't *conduter*, are they? Although the conducted person will be a *conductee*...

Answer (score 8):

It could be called a "host", for one, in case he invites people to a party which he is holding.

[Host](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/host_1#host_1__1)

Comment: "Hostess" is the female form of this meaning of "host".

Answer (score 0):

I think "Host" is the closest answer, although in some cases it could be "Sponsor".

However, I don't think "inviter" is the answer at all (according to dictionary.com)
in reality there is no straightforward word in English for that, I guess it has skipped usage all these years.